# I want to insert the model[i].marker.addListener function outside the loop

Tags: javascript

```
function pushMarkers() {
    locInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        var loc = model[i].places;
        var title = model[i].title;
        model[i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: loc,
            title: title,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            id: i
        });
        console.log(model[i].title);
        model[i].marker.addListener('click', function() {
            console.log('InfoWindow Loop entered');
            toggleBounce(this);
            populateInfoWindow(this, locInfo);
        });
        wikiLink(model[i].marker);
    }
}
```

Its not advisable to make functions within a loop so i want to make the function outside the loop.

Comment: you have a typo, unless I'm mistaken it should be `model[i].marker.addEventListener` not `.addListener`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make multiple functions at all, in point of fact, you should just make it once and then attach it as a listener in the loop.  such that:

```
function handleMarkerClick() {
   console.log('InfoWindow Loop entered');
   toggleBounce(this);
   populateInfoWindow(this, locInfo);
}

model[i].marker.addEventListener('click', handleMarkerClick);
```

Note that if you need to pass contextual information to that handleMarkerClick function that's only available inside the loop, let's say you want it to know the index (i) for some reason, you can bind it:

```
model[i].marker.addEventListener('click', handleMarkerClick.bind(model[i].marker, i);
```

and then the signature of the function would need to be  `function handleMarkerClick(i, event){}`